# wicket ajaxButton onError called

Tags: wicket-6

I am working on wicket 6.0. I used an AjaxButton to save a form. When I press the button, nothing happens on User Interface. However I checked the log and the onError method was called. What does it mean? How to fix it?

Moreover I checked on FireBug to see Ajax events, I have no events when I press the button.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AjaxButton is a form submitting component. If its `#onError()` is called that means some FormComponent in the submitted form didn't pass its validation/conversion.

If `#onError()` is called then there is an Ajax call for sure!